# Merge two unequal dataframes with partially common elements on the two indices (datetime and date)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes of different length on two columns which have a common element partially.

The index of the left_dataframe (A) is of `datetime` type and the same date will appear multiply but with different times (hence, `index.date` does not help).

The index of the right_dataframe (B) is of `datetime.date` type and each date is distinct, as expected.

```
A=pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['2019-06-01 18:11:55', '2019-06-01 21:43:02','2019-07-23 09:07:18', '2019-07-24 10:32:24'], \
                'value 1':[2, 5, 80, 0]})

B=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-06-01', '2019-07-23', '2019-07-24'], \
                'value 2':[10, 7, 3]})
```

I need to merge the two dataframes on dates and, particularly, by placing the elements of B at the rows where the first new date appears and filling in the rest same-dates-different-times with `0`, so the output should be something like this (along with comments):

```
           datetime  value 1  value 2
2019-06-01 18:11:55        2       10  #this is the first 2019-06-01 --> so it got the value of dataframe B
2019-06-01 21:43:02        5        0  #this is the second 2019-06-01 --> so the value 2 column got filled in with a 0 value
2019-07-23 09:07:18       80        7
2019-07-24 10:32:24        0        3
```

Your input is more than welcome ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert columns to dates
B['date'] = pd.to_datetime(B['date']).dt.date
#convert to columns datetimes
A['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(A['datetime'])
```

Create new columns - `date`s from `datetime`s in `A` by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for match by `B['date']` and helper columns for merge by duplicates of `date`s by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
A['date'] = A['datetime'].dt.date
A['g'] = A.groupby('date').cumcount()
B['g'] = B.groupby('date').cumcount()

#print (A)
#print (B)
```

Then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with both columns and left join, remove helper column and convert missing values of added column to `0` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = A.merge(B, on=['date','g'], how='left').drop(['date','g'], axis=1)
df['value 2'] = df['value 2'].fillna(0, downcast='int')
print (df)
             datetime  value 1  value 2
0 2019-06-01 18:11:55        2       10
1 2019-06-01 21:43:02        5        0
2 2019-07-23 09:07:18       80        7
3 2019-07-24 10:32:24        0        3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael for your very clear and short code. Worked great!